# two php objects refers the same instance

Tags: php, oop

I create instances of the same class with inside a for loop. But it seems that these instances refer the same object somehow.

Here is the code;

```
class Content{
    /**
     * current content id
     * @var int 
     */
    public $id;

    function __construct($id){
        echo " <br>Construct content ".$id;
    }

    function createContentOfPage($id){
        $contentIdArray = $this->dbo->getContentIdsForPage($id);
        /*var_dump of $contentIdArray aray is given below*/
        if(is_array($contentIdArray) && count($contentIdArray)>0){
        $contentArray = array();    
            foreach ($contentIdArray as $Id){
                echo "<br>Content id: ".$Id['content_id'];
                array_push($contentArray, new Content(($id['content_id'])));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the var_dump of $contentIdArray

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["content_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["content_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

If I run the `createContentOfPage()` here is the out put;

```
Content id: 1 
Construct content 1
Content id: 2 
Construct content 1
```

What is that I'm doing wrong in here? Please help.

Comment: You're sure to confuse someone by using `$Id`, `$id`, and a member variable `$id` at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're using different ID variables:

```
echo "<br>Content id: ".$Id['content_id'];
array_push($contentArray, new Content(($id['content_id'])));
```

Use either `$Id` or `$id` consistently — in this case, you need to use `$Id`.

---

You should avoid the practice of shadowing variables like this. Call the array iterator variable `$contentId` and your parameter `$pageId`, or something like that.

Comment: ok! now I'm feeling like a retard for my self... :((
Thank you soo much